# how to insert a blank line without affecting the order in XSL-FO

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

The XML contains multiple PrintSections and they have multiple Text and Barcode sections. I need to **output a blank line after the first PrintSection** (or at least every PrintSection) **without changing the order** in which they are present in the XML.

XML

```
<Document>
    <PrintSection>
        <Text/>
        <Text/>
    </PrintSection>
    <PrintSection>
        <Text/>
        <Barcode/>
    </PrintSection>
    <PrintSection>
        <Text/>
        <Text/>
    </PrintSection>
</Document>
```

XSL

```
<xsl:template match="/">
.....
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Text">
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Text1" />
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Barcode">
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Barcode1" />
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

I tried adding this

```
<xsl:template match="PrintSection">
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Text" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Barcode" />
        <fo:leader/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

This inserts a blank line but it prints the Barcode at the very end changing the natural order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `space-before` property (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#space-before) on all `PrintSection` except the first:

```
<fo:template match="Document">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="PrintSection" />
</fo:template>

<fo:template match="PrintSection">
   <fo:block>
    <xsl:if test="position() > 1">
      <xsl:attribute name="space-before">1.4em</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

The template for `Document` is there just to show that all the `PrintSection` should be selected in one go so the `position()` in the `test` works as expected.  If it wasn't for the white-space text nodes between your `PrintSection` in your sample, that's what would happen anyway and the template shown for `Document` would be redundant.

Answer (score 1):

How about changing

```
<xsl:template match="PrintSection">
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Text" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Barcode" />
        <fo:leader/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

to

```
<xsl:template match="PrintSection">
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <fo:leader/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Yes! I knew it was something easy as that. Thanks :-)

Comment: Without explicitly specifying the leader length, it gets a default one of 0pt minimum, 12pt optimum and 100% maximum; this means there is **no guarantee** that it will be placed in an empty line instead of just at the end of a line containing the end of the preceding text; moreover, the "empty" line could appear at the top of the page. I think using `space-before` or `space-after`, as suggested in [Tony Graham's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35154424/4453460), is a cleaner approach.